# How to set color of placeholder of Chosen selection input?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, jquery-chosen

In my jQuery v3 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 application, I use chosen.jquery (Version 1.8.7) and I did not find how to set color of placeholder text of of Chosen selection input with styles like:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color:    #c2c200 !important;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color:    #c2c200 !important;
  opacity:  1 !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color:    #c2c200 !important;
  opacity:  1 !important;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color:    ##c2c200 !important;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color:    #c2c200 !important;
}

::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
  color:    ##c2c200 !important;
}
```

And I init it with code:

```
$(".chosen_select_box").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: "Nothing found!",
});
```

You can look at it this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1Lpdk79r/3/

But it does not work for chosen input. How to fix it?

Comment: What color are you trying to change?  The "select item" text, something like "pomme" in the dropdown list if chosen or something like "pomme" when it display as a pill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you view the source of your fiddle, you can see that the Chosen plugin generates a text input from your select, and adds the `placeholder` text as the input value.  It also styles that input.  So you just need to override the Chosen styling with your own.

This will do, to change text colour:

```
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
    color: #c2c200;
}
```

[Here's an updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/mg9ocsLh/2/) showing the result.